# SSO between Android App and web app using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on an Android app based on Firebase, most importantly Firebase Authentication. I see that it would be easier for my customers to have some content outside the app, e.g. on their existing website. It seems to be pretty common these days to have an app that integrates certain features from a web application into the native Android application.

The question is, how do I seamlessly integrate those two together, specifically the authentication part. E.g. how would I integrate a web based profile edit page to the native app, what mechanisms do I use so that the user only needs to sign in once (in the native app) and then is authenticated automatically also in the embedded web view?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to give a try to [openid library](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android) for SSO. I've no experience integrating openid with Firebase but I can see from the documentation that firebase supports [openid](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) standard. In addition, [here](https://www.gluu.org/blog/webviews-are-bad-use-appauth/) there's an article about Google that advice against the use of webviews in mobile apps

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I will have look into it. Do I understand this correctly - Chrome tabs should be used in favor of WebView when including external content, however it is safe to use WebView when I'm displaying content from my own domain?

Comment: Yeah I guess so. There's an interesting talk about chrome tabs, I watched it some days ago, hope you'll find it useful for your purpose: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DdQTXrk6YTk&feature=youtu.be